# Colorbox : how to pass and use data to the colorbox window ? (not an iframe)

Tags: colorbox

I think it's easy but I don't find the answer. I want to pass some data to a colorbox window and use them it. I did like that to open the colorbox:

```
$.colorbox({
    href:my_target, 
    iframe: false,
    open: true,
    width: "830px", 
height: "560px",
    speed: "0", 
    transition: "none", 
    opacity:0.5, 
    escKey: true, 
    overlayClose:true,
    data: {"test":"123456"}});
```

The colorbox is opened but I can't acces to the data "test".

How can I do that? Is it possible?

If this is not the right method, what is the good?

Comment: Why not set data on the container? `$('#colorbox').data("key", "value");` and then access it as such?

Comment: I could be indeed a solution. But if I write your code, juste the line after mine, the colorbox container is not updated with the data... Maybe a problem because the colorbox container is still not shown or created ? I tried to put your code in oncomplete function, and it doesnt work too... And to come back to my question, I thought there was a mechanism in colorbox which allow to pass directly data as I wrote it.

Comment: ok... i'm a bit tired. Your solution works. Of course I can add ! Thanks

Comment: Colorbox only allows passing of get / post parameters for ajax/iframe. Above way is working for html.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the general page model; when you are **not** using ColorBox's iframe option, the plugin and the content are just ordinary members of the DOM.  You can reference any variable from "inside" it just as you would with any javascript loaded by the page.

You would probably use ColorBox's event hooks to run functions that acted on the data.

Comment: Yes that's what I finally did with OnComplete and using .data().